# Loading data from an RPG game

Tags: java

So I'm working on a simple RPG game. I want to add an option to load progress through the game, but I guess I'm not that familiar with Java to do it without issues. The idea is to save the game on checkpoints, and load a saved data when the game continues. I'm getting an error with a `loadGame` method, and I guess it's related to the fact that the data I'm trying to load are all different data types. health and level are integers, while equippedItem is a string.

Here are just two methods, `saveGame`, and `loadGame`, because the code is a bit too long to simply paste it in the whole. I'll put additional code if needed of course.

```
public static void saveGame() {
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("savedGame.txt"));
        bw.write("Your health is " + player.getHealth());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("Your level is " + player.getLevel());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("" + player.equippedItem);
        bw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There's an error.");
    }
}
```

The `saveGame()` doing its work well, it stores the data in the file. The issue is with the `loadGame()` method.

```
public void loadGame() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("savedGame.txt"));
        player.getHealth();
        player.getLevel();
        player.equippedItem;
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There's an error.");
    }
}
```

The result of `player.getHealth()` and `player.getLevel()` is ignored, and it's probably the data type issue I've mentioned.

Comment: First step: **never** ignore the exception in a catch block, you need to know **what** error happened and where. Ideally you'd use a proper log system to print the exception to a log, but as a first step simply putting `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block will provide you with **way more** details about what goes wrong.

Comment: How would the `BufferedReader` you create and `player.getHealth()` etc. be related? You don't seem to actually read any data from `br` so how is that meant to happen? I'd expect something like `br.readLine()`, then some parsing of the line to get the numbers and finally calls to `player.setHealth(...)` etc.

Comment: Rather than trying to make an English-readable file, perhaps you should use a standard such as JSON or XML

Comment: @JoachimSauer > I just started learning exceptions, that's why I left a catch block with just a simple print statement. I've added `e.printStackTrace()` now, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @NomadMaker Usually, you don't want players to "alter" their saves directly as i.e. the amount of gold may be a limiting factor and by simply changing that value, well, you are open for cheating. Hence, I'd opt for a proprietary binary format, maybe even with a slight form of encryption and hash-checks

Comment: @RomanVottner I'm not disagreeing which what you're saying about cheating, but I'd stick to a simple text format while creating and debugging the game, and switch to an encrypted format when it's nearer to being finished. Though, to be honest, I've never worried about people cheating in anything I've programmed. But I've never programmed a commercial game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is creating a text file in *saveGame()*, 'opening' that save file in *loadGame()* but not accessing the data inside.

You have correctly created a BufferedReader, but you're using it incorrectly. You will need to use `br.readLine()` to read the text file which will return a string like "Your health is 123".

To update the state of the *player* with this data, you could add something like this inside *loadGame()*:

```
player.setHp(parseHp(br.readLine()));
player.setLevel(parseLevel(br.readLine()));
... // and so on
```

The parse methods would take a String input like "Your health is 123" and return int 123.

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for! I've adjusted it to my code and it works now. Thanks!